# What is the use of MongoDB indexing?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection with millions of documents having same fields, For example,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601ade833126047ee8f47182"),
    "file_id" : "60110b7dad0cf20001adcbef",
    "versions" : [
        {
            "local" : 6,
            "s3" : "C71rczduuVOPpMohCpCeBQ3_NARDnTRj"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60221d1039acf39e09fbfca5"),
    "file__id" : "5fdb2eb4ad0cf20001f97856",
    "versions" : [
        {
            "local" : 2,
            "s3" : "aCy61Gx_UpTZfY59hNLYryGuWTJO2oPk"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60221dc639acf39e09fbfca6"),
    "file_id" : "5fe9c897a675f20001f0a82e",
    "versions" : [
        {
            "local" : 3,
            "s3" : "PHLnYjsRlg3GnEQ_UeDkhWIaJbFRmpw9"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6050cbcd6b7aab2cd3958978"),
    "file_id" : "6040ca06a675f2000115985e",
    "versions" : [
        {
            "local" : 2,
            "s3" : "vdFY22JFAzU.cD1Xr0eliuwt00rpJC8j"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, if I give the command `collection.find({"file_id": some_string})`, mongodb has to search the whole collection to find the document with "**file_id**" which I am searching for. Will Indexing "**file_id**" help to reduce the execution time?. In my case all the documents inside the collection will have the key "**file_id**". Will indexing really help in this case?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Will Indexing "file_id" help to reduce the execution time?

The answer is that, quite possibly, yes, adding an index to the `file_id` field will dramatically speed up the find query you showed above.  Just try it yourself to find out:

```
db.your_collection.createIndex( { "file_id": 1 } )
```

The above command will, by default, create a *B-tree* index using the `file_id` field values.  Going into depth about how a B-tree works might be out of scope for any single answer, but in summary if Mongo uses this index to search by `file_id` it should perform as `O(lgN)`, where `N` is the number of BSON documents in your collection.  On the other hand, running your query as-is, without any index, should result in a full collection scan, which should be a linear `O(N)` operation.  Note that this is *exponentially* slower than using the index.

Comment: Thanks for answering, my doubt is, all the documents in my collection will have the key "file_id". In that case even if I index, mongodb has to search the whole document anyway right?. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AjayGanesan If you add an index on `file_id`, then Mongo should only have to handle a very small subset of all documents.  This assumes that `file_id` is a relatively unique field.  Obviously, if all documents were to have the same `file_id` value, then the index wouldn't help.

Comment: In my case all the documents will have the key "file_id" but the value is unique to each document. will indexing help now?

Comment: @AjayGanesan Read about [cardinality in SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)), which still applies to Mongo in this case.  Yes, if `file_id` is a fairly unique field across your collection, then the index should help.  As duplicate values become more common, the usefulness of the index will start to decrease.